# Short story about land where wealth determines one's worth as a human

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story as a child, in 2005 or earlier. I do not remember much of it. I do not know when it was published or written. I don't believe it was particularly aimed for children - in fact, the book had scholarly footnotes explaining the story.

I remember two details of the story quite vividly: The story concerns a land where one's wealth determines one's self worth. The richest people are believed to be gods, while the poorest people have a status of animals. There was regular sacrifice of the poorest people to the richest as part of serving them as gods. There is also I believe lots of theft and murder, as people are desperate to have money (I may be misremembering that exact detail). The people end up on a star or a planet made of gold at some point in the story.

The second detail is that there is a sword that can win any war via swooshing it. It has the ability to instantly vaporize one's enemies.

There's also a king and a queen and other fantasy tropes.

It was in a collection of other short stories, and it had a lot of footnotes, which still sticks out to me today, though I do not recall if the footnotes were part of the story or I was reading an annotated edition.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing our own world

Comment: @Valorum our own world has a sword that can win any war via vapo.... oh wait.

Comment: Is it " The Book of the New Sun" by Gene Wolfe? It's a Sci-Fi Fantasy novel that consists of 4 volumes. Your description of the world where wealth determines one's worth is similar to its second volume "The Claw of the Conciliator".

Comment: @Sandun no, it's not that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "The Master of Prayer" by Rebbe Nachman, one of Rebbe Nachman's [famous thirteen tales](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Tales_of_Rabbi_Nachman), which date back to the 1870s. The story is a religious fairy tale designed to impart various lessons. The footnotes are an attempt to explain the story. I read Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's annotated version of the tales, titled "Rebbe Nachman's Stories", originally published in 1985.

The specific tale annotated by him is available online [here](http://israel613.com/books/MASTER-PRAYER-E.pdf).

(A friend helped me figure it out as he recalled reading it as well).